# copy first letters from string to another string

Tags: c++

Well, I tried to find an answer to my question.

Basically, I have two `string` variables, and I want to copy the first letters until to space, to another `string` variable, but without success. I can't use `strcpy()`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
    
int main() {

    string string1;
    string string2;

    cout << "String1:" << endl;
    getline(cin, string1);

    for (int i = 0; (i < string1.length()) && (string1[i] != ' '); i++){
        string2[i] = string1[i];
    }

    cout << string2;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `string2` is defined to be empty, therefore `string2[i]` is undefined.

Use `string2.push_back(string1[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

`string2` is empty, so you can't copy from `string1[i]` into `string2[i]`.
You can append to the string like this though:

```
string2 += string1[i];
```

> but with insuccess. I can't use the strcpy.

No need. `std::string` has a copy assignment operator and a `substr` member function so to copy the part of the string before the first space:

```
std::string string2;

auto pos = string1.find(' ');

if(pos != std::string::npos) {        // space found
    string2 = string1.substr(0, pos); // copy the substring [0, pos)
} else {
    string2 = string1;                // copy te whole string
}
```

If `pos` returns `npos` you can use that to copy the whole string, so you could strip the `if`/`else` above:

```
std::string string2;

auto pos = string1.find(' ');

string2 = string1.substr(0, pos);
```

So your loop is not needed.

You could construct `string2` directly from the `find` too:

```
std::string string2(string1, 0, string1.find(' '));
```

Comment: You don't need to check `pos` for `string:::npos` in this example. `substr(0, npos)` will copy the entire string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that's similar to what the alternative `std::string string2(string1, 0, string1.find(' '));` does (only on construction). I did the `npos` test though so OP sees how to check if a certain character is found or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. Just use standard C++ library:

```
auto pos = string1.find(' ');
string2 = (std::string::npos == pos) ? string1 : string1.substr(0, pos);
```

PS: Remy is right, you [can](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) use `std::string::npos` as second argument in `substr`. So it will be even simplier:

```
string2 = string1.substr(0, string1.find(' '));
```

Comment: Can you explain the second line

Comment: You don't need the `?:` operator in this case, `string2 = s1.substr(0, pos);` will work fine. If `pos` is `string::npos`, `substr(0, npos)` will copy the entire string.

Comment: @NunoDomingues  ?: operator is just a simplified `if` - It will assign entire `string1` or its substring, depending on `find` returning `npos`.

Comment: `?:` is often called [the conditional operator or ternary operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).